# Error al uilizar Vlook up con VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hice esta macro para tomar los datos de una tablas ubicadas en muchas pestañas de un solo Archivo(A) a otro archivo (B).

sin embargo al momento de yo intentar usar vlookup tengo un error indicando
"Application-defined or object-defined error"

He colocado varias mensajes de alerta para asegurarme que el rango sea el correcto, he incluso
selecciono las celdas pero no logro corregirlo, algun consejo??

```
Private Sub macro()
On Error Resume Next
Dim Cont As Integer, rango As Range
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, i As Integer, J As Integer, lnCol As Long, lnRow As Long
Dim rcol As Integer
Dim result As Long
Dim LV As String
Dim FoundRange, rng As Range
Dim HG As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Seleccionar folder o directorio donde se encuentra Reporte
directory = "C:\Users\edgar.soto\Desktop\Horas Barmachine Inline\LOB Report\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??") '<-- you can use * and ? wild cards here.
    
    Do While fileName <> ""
    'Se abre reporte del directorio colocado
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
    fileName = Dir()
'ciclo FOR para tomar informacion de las ultimas 40 hojas del documento
    For i = Workbooks(2).Sheets.Count - 40 To Workbooks(2).Sheets.Count
       ' MsgBox Workbooks(2).Sheets(i).Name
        Set FoundRange = Workbooks(2).Sheets(i).Cells.Find("PJZILBMMK01", MatchCase:=False)
        'MsgBox FoundRange.Address
        fecha = DateAdd("d", 0, Workbooks(2).Sheets(i).Name)
        
       ' MsgBox FoundRange.Row & ", " & FoundRange.Column
        lnRow = FoundRange.Row - 1
        lnCol = Workbooks(2).Sheets(i).Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="Sum of GainedHours", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
        rcol = lnCol - FoundRange.Column + 1
        Workbooks(1).Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 2 + Cont).Value = fecha
         For J = 2 To 25
         ' Set rng = FoundRange.Resize(20, rcol)
          Set rng = Workbooks(2).Sheets(i).Range("G53:M77")
          
          'Set rng = Workbooks(2).ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J4")
          Set Table_Range = Workbooks(2).Sheets(i).Range("B4:F11")
         rng.Select
          
          LV = Workbooks(1).Sheets("Data").Cells(J, 1).Value
          result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LV, rng, lnCol, False)
                  'Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, myrange, 2, False)
         Next J
        'MsgBox FoundRange.Address
       Cont = Cont + 1
    Next i
 Loop
 'Range(Cells(FoundRange.Row, FoundRange.Column), Cells(FoundRange.Row + 25))
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Cuál es el código del error?

Comment: Tienes puesto `On Error Resume Next` al principio de tu código. Deberías eliminarlo y depurarlo sin ese comando. Respecto a VLOOKUP, comrpueba el valor de `rng`, de`LV` y de `lnCol` cuando te da error. Recuerda que puedes depurar con F8

Comment: @Esei  Si, esa parte la coloque para ver la salida la funcion de vlookup (lo cual es nada) . coloque varios MsgBox para ver  los valores de esas variables antes de entrar al Vlookup y me sigue indicando el error. El rango lo comprobe con rng. Address y todo se ve bien.